# DataTable in Bokeh - How do you hide the index column?

Tags: python, bokeh

How do you hide the index header column in a bokeh DataTable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It took me a long time to figure this one out, so I wanted to post it:

According to the [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html):

> ### index_position
>
> *property type: Int*
>
> Where among the list of columns to insert a column displaying the row index. Negative indices are supported, and specify an index position from the end of the list of columns (i.e. standard Python behaviour).
>
> **To prevent the index column from being added, set to None.**
>
> If the absolute value of index_position is larger than the length of the columns, then the index will appear at the beginning or end, depending on the sign.

So, set `index_position=None` like so:

```py
table = DataTable(..., index_position=None, ...)
```

Comment: also, there is index_header option if you want to change name of #